# How to stop fixed sidebar on footer?

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar which is fixed on scroll. Once it reaches the footer it overlaps footer because of fixed position. So i want to remove the fixed position when sidebar reaches footer.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyform').offset().top;
    var footer_top = $(".footer").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop > footer_top ) {
            $('#stickyform').css({position: 'fixed', top: '105px', width: '328px'});
        } else {
            $('#stickyform').css({position: 'static', top: '0px', width:'100%' , padding: '0px'});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `How to stop fixed sidebar on footer` What does this mean? It could mean a thousand things. Can you please explain what you are trying to do, what the start scenario is and what the expected outcome is.

Comment: I have a sidebar which is fixed on scroll once it reach on footer then it overlaps on footer because of fixed position. So i want to remove the fixed position when sidebar  reach on footer.

Comment: Please update the post with your question, it will get lost in comments.